# Composition Flowchart in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

Need your expertise. I can't seem to figure out how to delete Scene 07 in Media 3.3 and to reference it to another Media. Is there a way to edit the composition flowchart? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the flow chart directly, but you can duplicate any comp from the project window, then replace another comp with your duplicate - see this answer: [How to duplicate composition and subcompositions?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/how-to-duplicate-composition-and-subcompositions/26024#26024)